# Google+ integration for the new Friends App

Tags: 13.04, google-plus

On Ubuntu 13.04, I do not see a way to integrate Google+ feed data into the Friends app. This option is available for Twitter and Facebook. Is Google+ feed data integration on the cards anytime soon?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there exists no native OAuth-authenticated API GET.

https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=96&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Component

It makes it hard to implement.

Good question though ;)